# RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N] : what it does in .htaccess

Tags: regex, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

One in laravel project I found a piece of code for .htaccess url rule but not understanding what it does actually, I tried well to find it on google but no success.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
```

**what is meaning of this `RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]` regex ?**

*Update*: full .htaccess file to remove public/ from laravel url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: The `N` flag is just a “go to top”, makes the rewriting process start from the beginning again. I am not able to make sense of `^$1` though - no idea what the `^` should achieve in that place, and neither where `$1` would be supposed to come from, since there is no capturing of anything going on (at least not in what you have shown, maybe there’s more.)

Comment: updated with full .htaccess code, only solution which works like a charm

Comment: To confirm, this `.htaccess` file is in the document root? Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory? Your URLs don't actually contain `/public`? Where is `server.php` located? Do you know where these directives originated? (The identical block of directives seems to have popped up a few times recently? I've [found the same on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/liaotzukai/8e61a3f6dd82c267e05270b505eb6d5a) - no explanation - that is at least 2 years old.)

Comment: What is the format of your URLs? Do they always contain a "file extension" eg. `.html`?

Comment: no, my urls are without extension